# regular expression on string into array

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to regular expressions in PHP so I was wondering how would I split the below soe that all "somethings" are stored in an array?

```
$string = "something here (9), something here2 (20), something3 (30)";
```

Desired result:

```
$something_array = array(
[0] => something 
[1] => something2
[2] => something3 )
```

Basically removing "," and whatever are in the brackets.

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression would be something like this: `(.*?) \([^)]*\),?`
It uses . (anything) because you requested so, but if it's a word you should use \w instead, or if it's anything but whitespace \S so it would be something like this: `(\S*) \([^)]*\),?`

Explaining the expression:

- `(.*?)` - match anything, but in lazy mode, or 'as little as possible'
  mode
- `[^)]*` - match anything but ) as many as possible
- `\([^)]*\)` -
  match a pair of brackets and it's content
- `,?` - match a comma if it's
  there

You can test it all these [HERE](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Finally, using the [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) PHP function, this would look something like this:

```
$str = 'something (this1), something2 (this2), something3 (this3)';
preg_match_all('/(\S*) \([^)]*\),?/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: I wrote the same regex, but you were 1 min faster. +1 for the explanation and the recommendation for the other character classes

Comment: This seems to only work if "something" is one word. How would you do it if it was for example: something here1 (30), something2 (10) I should probably note that the brackets should only contain numbers up to 100.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use regular expressions for something like this, but rather just PHP's [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) function.

```
$parts = explode(', ', $string);
$result = array_map(function($element) {
    return substr($element, 0, strrpos($element, ' '));
}, $parts);
print_r($result);
```

The above would output

```
Array
(
    [0] => something here
    [1] => something here2
    [2] => something3
)
```

Comment: I understand this the most as expressions are still very confusing to me but this only works if something is one word. How would I get the below to work: 

something here(10), something (20), something here again(30)

Comment: I have edited my origional example because I am having problems with using multiple words followed by numbers inside the brackets e.g.: book label (30), book label2 (100)